# Database in restoring state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

Hope to get a solution on my issue facing in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

One of my colleague mistakenly restored a database in my working database.

While getting restored he realize the error & cancelled the operation in between.

Now the database is in **RESTORING** state. I have a backup taken 20 mins before. But some transaction got punched are in a database which is in **RESTORING** state.

Is there any possibility to recover the database from restoring state?

I want to get the missing transactions data from this database.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks WITH RECOVERY  
GO
```

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/112/recovering-a-database-that-is-in-the-restoring-state/